# Can't map data from an API call in React using Axios

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I'm trying to fetch data from an api call and display them in react. The hooks part is working properly, but have problems parsing json response. I get the data.map is not a function error. Any advice to get this working would be appreciated.

Here is the API response

```
{"Field1":"XXX","Field2":"YYY","Field3":"ZZZ"}
```

And here is the code:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
const fetchData = async () => {
  const response = await axios(
    "http://www.myapi.com/?&search=mykeyword"
  );

  setData(response.data);
};
fetchData();
}, []);

return (
<div>
  <ul>
    {data.map(item => (
      <div key={item.Field1}>
        <div>{item.Field2}</div>
      </div>
    ))}
  </ul>
</div>
 );
}
```

Comment: Your response appears to be an object. `.map` is used to iterate through arrays.

Comment: @seanulus how can i change it?

Comment: Is the data returned really just a one-level object (No nested objects)?

Comment: there seems to be something off. Since you are accessing `Field1` and `Field2` from each item, but in the API response you have shown that they are `keys` in the object. In this case, why do you even need to iterate. ??

Comment: Can you console.log(response.data)  and share?